# Find an upperbound for the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find an upper bound for $$\frac{|x^3 - y^4|}{|x^2 + y^2|}$$ where $x, y $ are real.

I used the triangle inequality and got to:

$$\frac{|x^3 - y^4|}{|x^2 + y^2|} \le \frac{|x|x^2 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$$

But that is not a "nice" function. Help?

Comment: What happens when $y=0$ and $x\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: If $|x|>>|y|, |x|$. If $|y|>>|x|, y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this function is bounded above.

Then $\exists M>0$ such that $|f(x,y)|=\frac{|x^3-y^4|}{|x^2+y^2|} \leqslant M, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ \ $\{(0,0)\}$.

Take the sequence $x_n=(n,0)$ and you have that $|f(x_n,0)|=n \leqslant M ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Not maximum, I think OP ask upperbound.

Comment: i proved that the function is not bounded above

Comment: i did not assume tha it has a maximum value

Comment: Well, what is M? It seem maximum, though.

Comment: it is just an upper bound of the function.